# Why can I not make my new UIWindow appear over top of the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios9, uiwindow

I'm simply trying to place my `UIWindow` above the status bar temporarily for alert purposes.

The code is quite simple:

```
    let newwindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    newwindow.hidden = false
    newwindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    newwindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1.0
    newwindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    newwindow.hidden = false
```

However when I put that in `viewDidAppear` of my root view controller, I never see this window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to put it in `viewWillApper` or `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must retain `newwindow` somehow, like try to use a strong property. The rest of the code seems ok except for the fact that you call two times hidden